# How to center a row with images(Top/bottom)..Bootstrap-3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to align images inside a div row(having background image). For aligning images(left->right) i will be using offset. But now my row appears on top of the container. And now if i give margin-top to the row it works for the desktop but affects the mobile/tablet responsiveness. Can someone help me to align the row inside container.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="images/blueprint.png" class="img-responsive" id="book-img" />
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <img src="images/blueprint_logo1.png" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <img src="images/blueprint_logo2.png" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <img src="images/blueprint_logo3.png" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#book-img {
    position:absolute;
    background-position:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kc3s5/

Comment: Fiddle added. I also added a missing closing `div` tag.

Comment: I might need a little clarification. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, your `col-sm-4` and up classes are redundant. They all follow `col-xs-4` by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're looking for is a background on the container, this should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kc3s5/4

```
.container.has-bg {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x200/990000);
    background-size: cover;
}
```